# How to describe possible types for GraphQl schema

Tags: graphql

I have a query for which I have to describe the response types. Most of them are easy since they are of basic types or objects that contain basic types.
One however has as response two possible object types.
I am not sure about the syntax.

```
   query {
     complexObject {
      { field }
      {
       field
       field
      }
     }
     simpleObject {
       field
     }
   }
```

This feels the most natural, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out if it might help someone.

```
complexObject {
__typename
  ... on FirstObjectTypename {
    field
  }
  ... on SecondObjectTypename {
    field
    field
    field
  }
}
```